# mysqli_real_escape_string replace some characters with whitespace

Tags: php, mysqli

`mysqli_real_escape_string` replace some characters with whitespace like `+&€`
And `%<>` sometimes.
Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['msg'])) {
//
$msg = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['msg']);
 if(strlen($msg)>128) {
    die('<p id="red">Message CANNOT be more than 128 characters</p>');
 }
 if(strlen($msg)<5) {
     die('<p id="red">Message CANNOT be less than 5 characters</p>');
 }    
 //update msg
 $sbUpdate = $con->query('UPDATE sB SET un="'.$xun.'", msg="'.$msg.'" WHERE id ="0"');

 if($sbUpdate===TRUE) {
    echo('Sent!');
 }else {
     echo('Error! could not send.');
 }
 }else {
 echo('Error');
}
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, MySQL doesn't support double quotes. Use single quotes for values instead.

Second, if you refer to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), you'll see:

> Characters encoded are NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.

Third, there is this huge warning:

> ### Caution
>
> ## Security: the default character set
>
> The character set must be set either at the server level, or with the
>   API function `mysqli_set_charset()` for it to affect
>   `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. See the concepts section on character
>   sets for more information.

Depending on your charset, your characters might being swallowed.

Last, but not least, in order to avoid problems like this one, you'd better use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: So what if i really need to store & or +  in the db?

Comment: Also charset is utf8 in the db connect file.

Comment: `&` and `+` have no special meaning in quoted SQL strings, so you can do it.

Comment: The problem is, when i post it to the db it posted with whitespace instead of + or &, i checked it many times via PhpMyAdmin and by getting results printed by php, btw db engine is MyISAM, also i tried to post without escaping it still replace '+' with white space in db

Comment: You have to [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) your values if they come from an HTTP request.

Comment: Yes, it works well now, i used jquery to submit the text. Thanks was very helpful.